# Python match user input to element in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I am trying to match user input to an element in the list.
The goal is to allow the user to not type the whole name for the element because there are elements longer than 30 characters:

1. the result must contain all the characters in the input

   Ex: user input `foobar` matches with

   - `foobarxx`

   but not

   - `fobar`
2. extra characters between inputted keywords are allowed

   Ex: user input `abc` matches with:

   - `abc`, `a bc`, `axxbxxxc`
3. the most relevant result is selected

   Ex: `apple pie` matches with:

   - `apple tasty pie party`, `app legit piece`, `aXpXpXlXeX XpXiXe`

   However I only want the most relevant result, which is `apple tasty pie party`

**Code**

I have somehow achieved (1) and (2) using:

```py
enter = input("input: ")
all_element = ["orange", "apple pie", "pine apple pie", "ppap", "pen pineapple apple pen"]
pattern = ('(?:.+)?'.join(list(enter))).replace(" ", r"\s")
print(pattern)
results = {}
for full_name in all_element:
    all = re.findall(pattern, full_name)
    if all:
        results[len(max(all))] = full_name
print(results)
print(f"result: {results[max(results)]}\n")
```

result:

```
input: pen apple
p(?:.+)?e(?:.+)?n(?:.+)?\s(?:.+)?a(?:.+)?p(?:.+)?p(?:.+)?l(?:.+)?e
{22: 'pen pineapple apple pen'}
result: pen pineapple apple pen

input: ora
o(?:.+)?r(?:.+)?a
{3: 'orange'}
result: orange
```

I am currently trying to solve (3)

Based on the example in (3), My plan is to look at how many breaks happens, I know that:
- "`apple` tasty `pie` party" breaked 1 times, by the word " tasty"
- "`app` `le`git `pie`ece" breaked 2 times, one space and one "git"
- `a`X`p`X`p`X`l`X`e`X X`p`X`i`X`e` breaked n(X) number of times

The result with the least breaked times is selected, which is `apple tasty pie party`

From the code above I am just using the length of the matched element to select the result, which is inaccurate, since `ppap` results in `pen pineapple apple pen` instead of `ppap` itself:

```
input: ppap
p(?:.+)?p(?:.+)?a(?:.+)?p
{4: 'ppap', 21: 'pen pineapple apple pen'}
result: pen pineapple apple pen
```

So I am wondering how could I get the number of breaked times based on `(?:.+)?`, where

`result` should be:

```
{0: 'ppap', 2: 'pen pineapple apple pen'}
```

with the key is number of breaked times, and item as the selected element

such that I can simply use a `min()` to get the most relevant result

The question is how, do i need to write my own function or is there any regex pattern that can handle this

Comment: The first two requirements are totally inappropriate for regex; the third is subjective and not properly specified; the fourth is not meaningful after the first two are looked after. The overall question is much too broad with those requirements.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for your advice, can you give me a pointer on the way I could achieve the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` class from the `collections` module to quickly eliminate elements that do not match the first two criteria.  Then you can use the `SequenceMatcher` from the `difflib` to select the most relevant choice among the remaining elements.

```
import difflib
from collections import Counter

enter = input("input: ")
all_elements = ["orange", "apple pie", "pine apple pie", "ppap", "pen pineapple apple pen"]
cnts = Counter(enter)
for k,v in cnts.items():
    start = len(all_elements) - 1
    while start >= 0:
        if k not in all_elements[start] or all_elements[start].count(k) < v:
            del all_elements[start]
        start -= 1

results = {}
for elem in all_elements:
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=enter, b=elem)
    num = matcher.quick_ratio()
    blocks = len(matcher.get_matching_blocks())
    results[elem] = (num, blocks)

min_blocks = min([i[1] for i in results.values()])
min_elems = {k:v[0] for k,v in results.items() if v[1] == min_blocks}
print(max(min_elems, key=lambda x: min_elems[x]))
```

Comment: thanks alot, it gives me a new perspective to solve the problem, however if I use the test case from (3), `["apple tasty pie party","app legit piece","aXpXpXlXeX XpXiXe"]`, when i input apple pie it will return `"app legit piece"`, which is not the wanted `apple tasty pie party`

Comment: @ElectronX  I updated the code.  Hopefully it should work now

Comment: I did some adjustments to meet the priorities and it worked beautifully, thanks a lot. if it wasn't you I would have still been spinning around mindlessly. please take my token of appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

another possible way of comparing similar strings is using the Levenshtein module.

```
from Levenshtein import distance as lev

st = "apple pie"
l = ['apple tasty pie party', 'app legit piece', 'aXpXpXlXeX XpXiXe']


def find_best_match(some_list, st):

    return max((lev(st,s), s) for s in some_list)[1]


find_best_match(l, st)

apple tasty pie party
```

Comment: sadly I am currently working on windows and Levenshtein cannot be installed successfully. thanks for giving an alternative way

Comment: @ElectronX, if you have powershell, running pip install python-Levenshtein on powershell may install it for you.  I am currently on a windows machine.